# jQuery Smooth Scrolling is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, smooth-scrolling

I have this code for smooth scroll:

```
$(".navbar-nav li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

which is working for links like `<li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>` but it doesn't seem to work for links like: `<li><a href="#home#intro">Intro</a><li>` 
Any idea how to make the later link work ?

Comment: An element with 2 IDs?

Comment: The id is just one: intro, I'm using extra # in the url as a workaround for my angular app

Comment: What kind of workaround is that? That selector won't select any element.

Comment: Workaround is for handling anchor hash linking in angularjs

Comment: maybe try #home_intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double hash is not the good idea I think you should use data attribute to finding the ID.

By the way you can try this and keep the `#intro` as last value!

```
jQuery(".navbar-nav li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash_array = this.hash.split('#');
    var hash = hash_array[hash_array.length - 1];
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('#' + hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The control is not even going inside onClick function !!

Comment: How ? when selector is same which you've used in your question.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma Check the updated one there was some typo!

Answer (score 1):

A link with multiple #'s will not be able to be interpreted as to what "this.hash" you are trying to navigate to...perhaps something like this might work:

```
$(".navbar-nav li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = this.hash.split('#');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + hash[1]).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f31m3h6L/1/

Comment: By putting breakpoint, I can see that the control is not even going inside the onClick function

Comment: Can you please give me the link for that fiddle ?

Comment: In the above, the action is contained within the on click and functions how you are asking.